# Swift - Passing an UIImage to an UIImageView via delegation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, protocols

I'm out of ideas and I have no idea how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated.

I've got the following situation:

- MainViewController which points to a CollectionView embedded in a NavController
- CollectionView points to a DetailViewController
- DetailViewController shows the full picture chosen in the CollectionView and has a button which passes this image to the MainViewController. Protocol and delegate are used for this
- This image should now be shown in an UIImageView in the MainViewController

The delegation works. I have an UIImage in my MainViewController. BUT: the UIImageView is nil. So when I set the chosen Image as the imageView.image it crashes. The MainViewController is initialized and I also see my default Picture. See below for the code, and the console-output.

MainViewController

```
    class MainViewController: UIViewController, UserChosePhoto {

    @IBOutlet weak var googleImageView: UIImageView!
    var usedImage: UIImage? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        googleImageView.image = usedImage
        println("viewDidLoad: \(googleImageView)")
    }

    func userHasChosen(image: UIImage) {
        usedImage = image
        println("imageView: \(googleImageView)")
        println("delegation: \(image)")
    }
}
```

DetailViewController

```
 protocol UserChosePhoto {
    func userHasChosen(image: UIImage)
}

class GoogleDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bigImageView: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    var delegate: UserChosePhoto? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        bigImageView.image = image
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Use", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "tapped")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
        self.delegate = MainViewController()
    }

    func tapped() {
        if (delegate != nil) {
            self.delegate!.userHasChosen(bigImageView.image!)
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Console Output: the first viewDidLoad-log comes from the app launch. found 10 pictures - a log from an API-call. imageView - this is the imageView in question. delegation: here i have an UIImage

```
viewDidLoad: <UIImageView: 0x7f94825cabf0; frame = (180 159; 240 282); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f94825caeb0>> - (null)
found 10 pictures
imageView: nil
delegation: <UIImage: 0x7f94848344a0>, {213, 290}
```

Any tips would be cool - I'm really lost right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely the issue:

`self.delegate = MainViewController()`

Here you are setting the `DetailViewController`'s delegate to a *new* instance of `MainViewController` (hence the parenthesis).  You need to set the delegate to its parent (which is also of type `MainViewController`)

When you call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` you are now going back to your original `MainViewController` but the function `userHasChosen` was never called on this View Controller, and thus it crashes.

So, essentially what you need to do is make sure the `delegate` of your `DetailViewController` is set to its parent, which you might be able to get by just doing `myDetailViewController.parent` (Sometimes this doesn't work for me, but I'm not in XCode to test at the moment) or you can pass a reference of the parent to your child view controller and set that as its `delegate`.

EDIT: I made a few assumptions on how your code and view controller's are set up that may not be entirely accurate.  If your control flow indeed goes MainVC -> CollectionView -> DetailVC, then you may not be able to just get its "parent".  Instead you'll have to do the second part of my suggestion which is just pass a reference of your MainVC to your DetailVC and then you can use it in that ViewController instead of creating a new `MainViewController`.

And because it may be unclear:  When I refer to the `DetailViewController`'s parent, I mean the `MainViewController` in which it came from, not the CollectionView (even though the button from there is what took you to the DetailVC)

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I just passed a reference of my MainViewController to the DetailViewController and now it is working!

Comment: Make sure to specify the delegate as `weak` or you'll create a retain cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually setting the `image` property for the image view. The only time you do it is in `viewDidLoad` at which point it probably doesn't exist and you don't do it again. The action of setting it is a one time thing and does not bind the data, so you have to update it yourself any time you update the property. This should do it:

```
func userHasChosen(image: UIImage) {
        usedImage = image
        googleImageView.image = usedImage
        println("imageView: \(googleImageView)")
        println("delegation: \(image)")
    }
```

Another way (and arguably more neat) to do this would be to implement a `didSet` hook for your image property.

```
var usedImage: UIImage? = nil
{
    didSet
    {
        googleImageView.image = usedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Something else is going on somewhere in your `MainViewController`. Show more code from there that interacts with the image view.